# Detect HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a query regarding HTML5 video tags. I wanted to know if there is any way to check if the text to be added in the body tag contains a HTML5 video tag using jQuery or javascript.

```
<video>
     <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     <source src="demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

I cannot give any id or class to the video tag. 
I mean can we have something like

```
 if($('body').contains('<video>')){
      // do something
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: IMHO I say, learn about javascript and the way objects work, the way DOM interaction can be achieved and then jump for JQuery. It's not a crime doing JQuery first, but you will love learning JQuery once you know javascript :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to learn javascript first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 if($('video').length===0){
   //video not found
  }
```

Comment: Please reconsider `==` here in favor of `===`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum:Thanks benjamin. But how will it make the difference. .length is already integer type

Answer (score 6):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can use `getElementsByTagName()`

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
if (x.length) {
    //do code if element(s) are present
}
```

Comment: I think that edit radically changed my answer. Please post that as your own

Comment: I think it naturally compliments the answer with another pure JS approach. But if you disagree feel free to discard the edit.

Comment: It's not that it's wrong though, I'm not saying that.

Comment: @dfsq Check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code

Comment: @m59 Everyone decides for himself what is appropriate and not. If I want to improve an answer I do. Can't see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I might do `document.querySelectorAll("video")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked really nicely. But I cannot mark 2 answers as right.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("video").is(':visible')){
//do somthing
}
```

You can find HTML5 Video events here

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($( "body:has(video)" ).length)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
if($('video').length>0){
   console.log('Video tag exists');  // do operations.
}
```

Comment: You should check `.length`. `$('video')` itself returns an object which is never falsy.